# Handle populating state from multiple checkboxes

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I've got a form which builds a list of checkboxes from some data:

```
<fieldset className="visibility">
        <div className="input-container checkbox">
          <span className="label">Visible to</span>
          <ul>
            {
              allForces.map(force => {
                if (force.name !== 'White' && force.name !== currentMarkerForce) {
                  return (
                    <li key={force.uniqid}>
                      <label>
                        <input onChange={handleVisibilityChange} name={`visibility-${_.kebabCase(force.name)}`} type="checkbox" value={force.name} checked={markerVisibleTo.includes(force.name) }/>
                        {force.name} cell
                      </label>
                    </li>
                  )
                }
              })
            }
          </ul>
        </div>
      </fieldset>
```

As it is usually at least 2 items that will appear and can be checked, I wrote a handler for it which populates an array before posting back to the state, the contents of this array is initially populated from the existing state:

```
 const visibilityChecked = [...markerVisibleTo]

  const handleVisibilityChange = ({ target }) => {
    const { checked, value } = target
    checked ? visibilityChecked.push(value) : visibilityChecked.pop(value)
    setMarkerVisibleTo(visibilityChecked)
}
```

The last line is a call to a `useState` hook this, mostly works but sometimes I get an odd behaviour where the wrong checkbox is selected:

[image: An example of the bug]

Can anyone please help shed some light on what is causing this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I may guess that happens because state update is asynchronous and by the time you attempt to apply changes with `setMarkerVisibleTo()` your state is different from the one you assume it is, you may try to put `const visibilityChecked = [...markerVisibleTo]` into `handleVisibilityChange()` body:

```
const handleVisibilityChange = ({ target }) => {
    const visibilityChecked = [...markerVisibleTo]
    const { checked, value } = target
    checked ? visibilityChecked.push(value) : visibilityChecked.pop(value)
    setMarkerVisibleTo(visibilityChecked)
}
```

Or, as I would write that:

```
const handleVisibilityChange = ({target:{checked,value}}) => {
    const visibilityChecked = checked ? 
        [...markerVisibleTo, value] : 
        [...markerVisibleTo].filter(val => val != value)
    setMarkerVisibleTo(visibilityChecked)
}
```

You may find full-blown demo over here:

```js
//dependencies
const { render } = ReactDOM,
      { useState } = React

//mocking source data      
const checkItems = [...'abcd']      

//check list component
const CheckList = ({items}) => {
  const [visibleMarkers, setVisibleMarkers] = useState(checkItems),
        onVisibilityChange = ({target:{checked,value}}) => {
            const visibilityChecked = checked ? 
                [...visibleMarkers, value] : 
                [...visibleMarkers].filter(val => val != value)
            setVisibleMarkers(visibilityChecked)
        }
  return (
  <div>
      <ul>
        {
          items.map((item,key) => (
            <li {...{key}}>
              <label>
                Option {item}
                <input 
                  type="checkbox" 
                  value={item} 
                  checked={visibleMarkers.includes(item)}
                  onChange={onVisibilityChange}
                />
              </label>
            </li>
          ))
        }
      </ul>
      <span>visibleMarkers: {JSON.stringify(visibleMarkers)}</span>
  </div>
  )
}

//render
render (
  <CheckList items={checkItems} />,
  document.getElementById('root')
)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.12.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script><script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.11.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script><div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: Yup. That did it :) I like the neatness of it too, I always forget `filter` exists as I rarely use it.